# PGFPlots - When setting ymin on bar plot, gap occurs between bars and the x-axis labels

Tags: bar-chart, axis, bar

I'm sing PGFPlots in pdflatex, I'am trying to set the minimum value of the y-axis to be 0. However, when i use the `ymin=0` command, I get a gap at the bottom of the graph, between the bars and the labels.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this? I tried setting `enlargelimts = false`, however, when I do this, the left and right most bars get split in half.

```
\begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        enlargelimits=0.1,
        ylabel={\%},
        symbolic x coords={Bar1, Bar2, Bar3, Bar4, Bar5},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabel style = {rotate=60,anchor=east},
        enlargelimits = true,
        grid,
        ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
        ymin=0,         
        width=10cm,
        bar width =1cm,
        ]
    \addplot[black,fill=lightgray] coordinates {(Bar1,50) (Bar2,60) (Bar3,50) (Bar4,75) (Bar5,80)};
\end{axis}
```

[image: Resulting Graph]

Comment: Hi, welcome! You are using `enlargelimits=0.1,` which is why the limits get enlarged. You may want to use `enlarge x limits=0.1` (perhaps combine with `enlarge y limits=false`) instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing this line also leads to the limits enlarging. The second part works however, Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [my above comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536180/pgfplots-when-setting-ymin-on-bar-plot-gap-occurs-between-bars-and-the-x-axis#comment1354475_536180). You have `enlargelimits=0.1,` and also `enlargelimits=true,` but you only seem to want to enlarge the `x limits`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
        ylabel={\%},
        symbolic x coords={Bar1, Bar2, Bar3, Bar4, Bar5},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabel style = {rotate=60,anchor=east},
        enlarge y limits =false,
        grid,
        ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
        ymin=0,ymax=90,         
        width=10cm,
        bar width =1cm,
        ]
    \addplot[black,fill=lightgray] coordinates {(Bar1,50) (Bar2,60) (Bar3,50) (Bar4,75) (Bar5,80)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace `enlargelimits = true` with `enlarge x limits = true, enlarge y limits = upper`.